# Detect a head/camera motion with aframe

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I'm in search for a motion detection in with a-frame. What I want to achieve is a detection if someone is moving his head when being in VR-Mode. Is there any property for an entity I can check? Or does the camera component itself has any position/rotaion/whatever attributes I can use for a detection?

Comment: What do you mean by not moving? People are never static. There will always be some movement.

Comment: I just want to detect the movement. Maybe I need threshhold to trigger events when some is moving/rotating his head etc. But I want to detect if there is a movement. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/core/entity.html#listening-for-component-changes

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('do-something-on-head-movement', {
  init: function () {
    var scene = this.el;
    var camera = scene.cameraEl;

    camera.addEventListener('componentchanged', function (evt) {
      if (evt.detail.name === 'rotation' || evt.detail.name === 'position') {
        // Do something.
      }
    });
  }
});

<a-scene do-something-on-head-movement>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this function to detect when the headset was put down (face down) to "pause" the app

```
function process(event) {
  var gamma = event.gamma;
  if((gamma < -10)||(gamma>5)){
    playApp();
  }else{
    pauseApp();
  }
}
```

http://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/spec-source-orientation.html